# While loop doesn't change the value of variable

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
int time=0;
int x=1;
int w=2;
int y=1;
int h=1;
int t=6;
while (x != w && y != h) {
    boolean s = Abc (a,b,c,time);
    if (s == true) {
        time = time+t;
        x++;
    }
    else if (s = false) {
        time = time++;
    }
}

System.out.println(time);
```

This is a part of program I'm writing for school and my problem is that when the program enters the while loop no matter what I do inside the loop when it exits and prints the variable "time" the value is the same as the value set at the beginning. Am I missing something? (BTW Abc is just a method that should return the value true when I first enter the loop, therefore the value of time should be changed to time+t)

Comment: Try with `else if (s == false)` (even if it is a little too overkill)

Comment: (s = false) should be: == false

Comment: `s = false` -> `s == false` else it will set `s` to false instead of comparing it, also `time = time++` does nothing. Use `time++` instead

Comment: The code you've posted will never enter the while loop, since `y` and `h` are equal.

Comment: You never need to compare a boolean; `if (s) { ... } else { ... }`;

Answer (score 7):

1. `s = false` is an assignment, not a comparison. Anyway, you don't need to test if `s == false`, you just need an `else` clause (since the original condition checks for `s == true`).
2. There's no reason to assign the result of `time++` to `time`, since it will undo the increment (the post increment operator returns the previous value of the variable, so when you assign that value back to the variable, you cancel the increment).

Change

```
else if (s = false) {
    time = time++;
}
```

to

```
else {
    time++;
}
```

Edit :

As Anthony Grist commented, even after these fixes, the entire while loop won't be executed at all, since `y==h` in the beginning.

Comment: Might be worth tipping a nod to @AnthonyGrist's comment, since these fixes don't make time change in and of themselves (UV anyway).

Comment: @AndyTurner I missed that. Thanks